# phpMyAdmin missing php-xml

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have an instance on AWS (Amazon Linux 2). I installed lamp on the server and access the phpMyAdmin.

And I get this error:

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require the following PHP extensions to be installed: xml

I tried to install it (php-xml) using `sudo yum install php-xml`, I get this error:

> Error downloading packages:
>
> php-xml-7.2.34-1.amzn2.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
>
> libxslt-1.1.28-6.amzn2.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

I am new to this, if you need more debugging information, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: There are great options within AWS for more managed services that mean you can just worry about code. What are you actually trying to achieve? Serve a website? Provide an API?

Comment: @shearn89 I want to serve a dynamic website (using PHP) with a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I accidentally delete some files in `/etc/pki/tls/certs/`. I put them back and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to deploy a PHP app then I would strongly recommend [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.html). You create a simple `appspec.yml` file, upload your code, and it does the rest - including database setup and sensible things like autoscaling. It will be much easier than setting everything up by hand!

Comment: Can I set up a ftp, which I can upload files directly into the AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Another question: You said it can autoscaling, does it mean I will auto increase the price?

Comment: I'm not sure about the FTP - but there are other ways of updating your app that AWS provide, take a look at the CodeStar tool. Autoscaling means it will add more servers as needed, and remove them when they're not. You only pay for what you use, so yes - it will cost more when the service is being heavily used!